# Bluetooth Messenger application crashing at start up itself

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I have tried to learn to write an application which is basically a bluetooth messenger. Things had been fine unless I tried to install and run it. It gets installed successfully but crashes down at start up itself. Can you please tell me what is wrong ?
This is the code for the main activity. There are three more activities apart from this.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

public final static String UUID = "3606f360-e4df-11e0-9572-0800200c9a66";

BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
BroadcastReceiver discoverDevicesReceiver;
BroadcastReceiver discoveryFinishedReceiver;

//---store all the discovered devices---
ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> discoveredDevices;
ArrayList<String> discoveredDevicesNames;

//---store all the paired devices---
ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices;    

static TextView txtData;
EditText txtMessage;

//---thread for running the server socket---
ServerThread serverThread;

//---thread for connecting to the client socket---
ConnectToServerThread connectToServerThread;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //---init the ArrayList objects and bluetooth adapter---
    discoveredDevices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
    discoveredDevicesNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    pairedDevices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();

    bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    //---for displaying the messages received---
    txtData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtData);
    txtMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}


//---make yourself discoverable---
public void MakeDiscoverable(View view)    
{     
    Intent i = new Intent(
        BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
    i.putExtra(
        BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
    startActivity(i);
}

/*
//---find all the previously paired devices---
private void QueryPairedDevices(){
    Set<BluetoothDevice> allPairedDevices = 
        bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
    //---if there are paired devices---
    if (allPairedDevices.size() > 0) {
        //---loop through paired devices---
        for (BluetoothDevice device : allPairedDevices) {
            //---add the name and address to an array adapter 
            // to show in a ListView---
            Log.d("UsingBluetooth", device.getName() + "\n" + 
                device.getAddress());
            pairedDevices.add(device);
        }
    }
}    
*/

//---used to discover other bluetooth devices---
private void DiscoveringDevices() {     
    if (discoverDevicesReceiver == null) {
        discoverDevicesReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {             
            //---fired when a new device is discovered---
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {                
                String action = intent.getAction();

                //---a device is discovered---
                if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                    //---get the BluetoothDevice object from 
                    // the Intent---
                    BluetoothDevice device = 
                        intent.getParcelableExtra(
                            BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                    //---add the name and address to an array 
                    // adapter to show in a ListView---
                    //---only add if the device is not already 
                    // in the list---
                    if (!discoveredDevices.contains(device)) {
                        //---add the device---
                        discoveredDevices.add(device);

                        //---add the name of the device; used for 
                        // ListView---
                        discoveredDevicesNames.add(device.getName());

                        //---display the items in the ListView---
                        setListAdapter(new 
                            ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(),
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
                            discoveredDevicesNames));  
                    }                    
                }
            }
        };
    }

    if (discoveryFinishedReceiver==null) {
        discoveryFinishedReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            //---fired when the discovery is done---
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                //---enable the listview when discovery is over; about 12 seconds---
                getListView().setEnabled(true);     
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                        "Discovery completed. Select a device to start chatting.", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                unregisterReceiver(discoveryFinishedReceiver);
            }               
        };
    }

    //---register the broadcast receivers---
    IntentFilter filter1 = new
        IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    IntentFilter filter2 = new
        IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);

    registerReceiver(discoverDevicesReceiver, filter1);
    registerReceiver(discoveryFinishedReceiver, filter2);

    //---disable the listview when discover is in progress---
    getListView().setEnabled(false);
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
            "Discovery in progress...please wait...", 
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
}

//---discover other bluetooth devices---
public void DiscoverDevices(View view)    
{
    //---query for all paired devices---
    //QueryPairedDevices();           

    //---discover other devices---
    DiscoveringDevices();        
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();        
    //---cancel discovery of other bluetooth devices
    bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

    //---unregister the broadcast receiver for 
    // discovering devices--- 
    if (discoverDevicesReceiver != null) {
        try {
            unregisterReceiver(discoverDevicesReceiver);                
        } catch(Exception e) {

        }
    }

    //---if you are currently connected to someone...---
    if (connectToServerThread!=null) {            
        try {
            //---close the connection---
            connectToServerThread.bluetoothSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }        
    //---stop the thread running---
    if (serverThread!=null) serverThread.cancel();
}

//---used for updating the UI on the main activity---
static Handler UIupdater = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {              
        int numOfBytesReceived = msg.arg1;
        byte[] buffer = (byte[]) msg.obj;
        //---convert the entire byte array to string---
        String strReceived = new String(buffer);
        //---extract only the actual string received---
        strReceived = strReceived.substring(
            0, numOfBytesReceived);
        //---display the text received on the TextView---              
        txtData.setText(txtData.getText().toString() + 
            strReceived);
    }
};

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //---start the socket server---
    serverThread = new ServerThread(bluetoothAdapter);
    serverThread.start();
}




//---when a client is tapped in the ListView---
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, 
int position, long id) {
    //---if you are already talking to someone...---
    if (connectToServerThread!=null) {
        try {
            //---close the connection first---
            connectToServerThread.bluetoothSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", e.getLocalizedMessage());             
        }
    } 

    //---connect to the selected Bluetooth device---
    BluetoothDevice deviceSelected =
        discoveredDevices.get(position);        
    connectToServerThread = new 
        ConnectToServerThread(deviceSelected, bluetoothAdapter);
    connectToServerThread.start();

    //---tell the user that he is connected to who---
    Toast.makeText(this, "You have connected to " + 
            discoveredDevices.get(position).getName(), 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();        
}

 private class WriteTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    protected Void doInBackground(String... args) {
        try {
            connectToServerThread.commsThread.write(args[0]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
}

//---send a message to the connected socket client---
public void SendMessage(View view) 
{    
    if (connectToServerThread!=null) {
        ///=========
        //connectToServerThread.commsThread.write(
        //      txtMessage.getText().toString());

        new WriteTask().execute(txtMessage.getText().toString());
        ///=========

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Select a client first", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

}
```

ServerThread class :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.UUID;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.util.Log;

public class ServerThread extends Thread {    
//---the server socket---
private final BluetoothServerSocket bluetoothServerSocket; 

public ServerThread(BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter) {        
    BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;
    try {
        //---UUID must be the same for both the client and 
        // the server---
        tmp =     
            bluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(
                "BluetoothApp", UUID.fromString(MainActivity.UUID));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("ServerThread", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    bluetoothServerSocket = tmp;
}

public void run() {
    BluetoothSocket socket = null;

    //---keep listening until exception occurs 
    // or a socket is returned---
    while (true) {
        try {
            socket = bluetoothServerSocket.accept();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("ServerThread", e.getLocalizedMessage());
            break;
        }
        //---if a connection was accepted---
        if (socket != null) {
            //---create a separate thread to listen for 
            // incoming data---
            CommsThread commsThread = new CommsThread(socket);
            commsThread.run();
        }
    }        
}

public void cancel() {
    try {
        bluetoothServerSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) { 
        Log.d("ServerThread", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
}
```

LogCat

```
04-13 18:25:06.684: D/AndroidRuntime(397): Shutting down VM
04-13 18:25:06.684: W/dalvikvm(397): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
04-13 18:25:06.704: E/AndroidRuntime(397): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-13 18:25:06.704: E/AndroidRuntime(397): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume    activity {net.learn2develop.usingbluetooth/net.learn2develop.usingbluetooth.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-13 18:25:06.704: E/AndroidRuntime(397):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2120)
04-13 18:25:06.704: E/AndroidRuntime(397):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
04-13 18:25:06.704: E/AndroidRuntime(397):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1668)
04-13 18:25:06.704: E/AndroidRuntime(397):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-13 18:25:06.704: E/AndroidRuntime(397):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
04-13 18:25:06.704: E/AndroidRuntime(397):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-13 18:25:06.704: E/AndroidRuntime(397):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-13 18:25:06.704: E/AndroidRuntime(397):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-13 18:25:06.704: E/AndroidRuntime(397):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-13 18:25:06.704: E/AndroidRuntime(397):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-13 18:25:06.704: E/AndroidRuntime(397):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-13 18:25:06.704: E/AndroidRuntime(397):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-13 18:25:06.704: E/AndroidRuntime(397):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-13 18:25:06.704: E/AndroidRuntime(397): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-13 18:25:06.704: E/AndroidRuntime(397):  at net.learn2develop.usingbluetooth.ServerThread.<init>(ServerThread.java:21)
04-13 18:25:06.704: E/AndroidRuntime(397):  at net.learn2develop.usingbluetooth.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:235)
04-13 18:25:06.704: E/AndroidRuntime(397):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1150)
04-13 18:25:06.704: E/AndroidRuntime(397):  at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3832)
04-13 18:25:06.704: E/AndroidRuntime(397):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
04-13 18:25:06.704: E/AndroidRuntime(397):  ... 12 more
04-13 18:25:08.764: I/Process(397): Sending signal. PID: 397 SIG: 9
04-13 18:25:10.354: D/AndroidRuntime(415): Shutting down VM
04-13 18:25:10.354: W/dalvikvm(415): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
04-13 18:25:10.364: E/AndroidRuntime(415): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-13 18:25:10.364: E/AndroidRuntime(415): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {net.learn2develop.usingbluetooth/net.learn2develop.usingbluetooth.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-13 18:25:10.364: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2120)
04-13 18:25:10.364: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
04-13 18:25:10.364: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1668)
04-13 18:25:10.364: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-13 18:25:10.364: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
04-13 18:25:10.364: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-13 18:25:10.364: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-13 18:25:10.364: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-13 18:25:10.364: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-13 18:25:10.364: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-13 18:25:10.364: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-13 18:25:10.364: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-13 18:25:10.364: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-13 18:25:10.364: E/AndroidRuntime(415): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-13 18:25:10.364: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at net.learn2develop.usingbluetooth.ServerThread.<init>(ServerThread.java:21)
04-13 18:25:10.364: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at net.learn2develop.usingbluetooth.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:235)
04-13 18:25:10.364: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1150)
04-13 18:25:10.364: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3832)
04-13 18:25:10.364: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
04-13 18:25:10.364: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  ... 12 more
04-13 18:25:13.304: I/Process(415): Sending signal. PID: 415 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Please include a readable copy of your logcat.

Comment: @323go : I included a readable copy of LogCat

Comment: Check ServerThread, line 21 -- There's an NPE there. See what's null and fix it.

Comment: please write row number 235 in MainActivity

Comment: @xoxol_89 : I couldn't get you. Please elaborate.

Comment: @323go : Should I post ServerThread ? Will you please check it ?

Comment: so in your logs i see that error in MainActivity, row 235. so what is it?

Comment: @xoxol_89 : I think that error is due to something messed up in the class ServerThread.java. Should I post it here ?

Comment: Rahul, can you paste in your question row 235?

Comment: `serverThread = new ServerThread(bluetoothAdapter);
 serverThread.start();` - This is line 235 & 236

Comment: `public ServerThread(BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter) {        
        BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;
        try {
            
                bluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(
                    "BluetoothApp", UUID.fromString(MainActivity.UUID));
        } catch (IOException e) {
         Log.d("ServerThread", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        bluetoothServerSocket = tmp;
    }` @323go : This is the culprit for NPE in ServerThread.java; how do I fix this ?

Comment: Is `bluetoothAdapter` null on this line in your activity `serverThread = new ServerThread(bluetoothAdapter);`?

Answer (score 0):

Possible changes you can try which might help you.

In `ServerThread.java`

```
public void run() {
   ....
   while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
   //do something
   }
}
```

If this works fine, otherwise try:
In `MainActivity.java`

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
   ....
   //Start your thread here
   //---start the socket server---
    serverThread = new ServerThread(bluetoothAdapter);
    serverThread.start();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //handle your thread here - the following maynot be helpful, but logiaclly speaking,       //you must handle your threads here
    if(serverThread.isAlive())
       serverThread.resume();
    else
       serverThread.interrupt();
}
```